# cron job to move 10 day old files to different directory

Tags: file, cron, move

I need a script that I can run from a cron job to move files that are 10 days old or older to a different directory.  Being a windows sys admin, I have no idea what I'm doing in linux.  :(   Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    find /source/directory/* -mtime +10 -exec mv "{}" /my/directory \;
```

Use 'crontab -e' to open your crontab and set it to run as needed.

Comment: I get an error that reads "find: missing argument to `-exec'"

Comment: Sorry about that, needed a space before the ;

Comment: I'm slow today. So sorry. Backslash too. 

Works now I promise :(

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much!